Hololens 2 d3d11.dll could not be found
I'm writing some code using SharpDX which requires Direct3D.
I've written my project in a clean Unity 3d project built for UWP with just my SharpDX scripts. When run on the Hololens 2 I get the following error:
Unable to load DLL 'd3d11.dll'. Tried the load the following dynamic libraries: Unable to load dynamic library 'd3d11.dll' because of 'Failed to open the requested dynamic library (0x06000000) - The specified module could not be found.  (WinError:0000007e)
If I'm not mistaken, d3d11.dll should be a system dll included on the device so I'm not sure why it isn't being found.
Here's the libraries I am using in my script:
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
using FFmpegInteropX;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Media.Core;
using Windows.Media.Playback;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using Windows.Graphics.DirectX;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#endif

Am I perhaps using a version that isn't compatible with the Hololens 2 or is there something else I'm missing? Any insight is greatly appreciated!
